# Compress CSS & JS code with PHPStorm?

Tags: javascript, css, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm. This is very great software for web developers.

When I want to compress my CSS & JS files in PHPStorm , I can't find any option in PHPStorm.

So, Please tell me how to compress CSS & JS code in PHPStorm.

Comment: Usually build scripts should do so, not IDE

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/minifying-javascript.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found [Assets Compressor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6740?pr=) plugin. See if it helps.

EDIT - Changed to the new link as pointed by @spade

Comment: I installed it but the plugin doesn't generate a minified document. Nothing happens

Comment: Click "Refactor >> Compress" to compress any file. This is a great plugin, definitely an up for the response.

Comment: As of phpstorm 2019.1.2 I get an error warning which cause this plugin to malfunction.

Answer (score 4):

PHPStorm supports minification by [File Watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/minifying-css.html). It supports integration with the YUI Compressor "out of the box", but it has some problems, e.g., [with calc() function](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/59). My solution is to use [minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minifier):

1. Repeat the steps to install Node.js and npm from [JetBrains manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/minifying-css.html)
2. Install minifier like YUI Compressor in manual (`npm install minifier`)
3. Minifier documentation says: "Installing through npm will create a binary (minify) in the usual locations", but I have not found it (perhaps it is not created on Windows). `Index.js` file can be executed via `node index.js` command, but PHPStorm does not maintain this way ("Please set program to run!" error will be thrown). So I created .bat file with the following content:

.

```
echo off
node path\to\minifier\index.js %*
```

4. Then in PHPStorm watcher settings in `Program` input field we set path to the .bat file. Note that Minifier uses a different method for setting the output path, so we have to change `Arguments` field: `$FileName$ --output $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems this has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minifier).

Answer (score 1):

See the related feature requests:

- [WEB-2138](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2138) Support automatic JavaScript and CSS minification
- [WEB-2125](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2125) Pre- and post-deployment commands

At the moment you can use third-party tools/plug-ins like suggested by @Pushpesh.